# Using a package only for certain tables

Tags: tables, packages, page-breaking, environments

I am using the `tabularx` environment since it the `X` component of the columns is very useful and necessary for the tables I want to produce. However, a single one of my tables is longer that a page, and I would like it to break over the page, without any of my other `tabularx` tables breaking over the page. Is there a way of doing this? I have found the `ltablex` package that will do the job of breaking the tables, but I don't wish it to apply to all my tables. Is it some way of using `\renewenvironment`?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{ltablex}    % This is the package I would like to apply to a single table
\usepackage{bigstrut} 
\begin{document} 

\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l X l|}
\hline
& \textbf{HEADING} & \textbf{HEADING} \bigstrut \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \bigstrut[t] \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \bigstrut[t] \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\end{tabularx}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

This has enough lines of text in it to go over the page length. I was thinking along the lines bringing the `ltablex` package down into the environment, and I need to retain the `X` functionality of the `tabularx` environment

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Instead of loading the `ltablex` package, you could consider loading the [ltxtable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable) package. An advantage of using the latter package is that it doesn't modify the `tabularx` environment. (The `ltxtable` package provides hooks for extending the `longtable` environment so that it accepts columns of type `X` a la `tabularx`.)

Comment: @Mico I was going to say that:-)  Or of course if you don't need the `X` feature in the long table use `longtable`

Comment: @Mico I want to modify the tabularx environment, and I want to use it, especially since I have many tables that work fine, and have already been coded, that I don't want to redo.

Comment: @Jubobs, I don't have a working example here, since I was asking for tables in general. I want to know how to make changes to how a single table operates that doesn't affect all of them.

Comment: I understand, but a minimal working example is good to get potentially helpful people started on your problem. Otherwise, they have to recreate the situation themselves, which takes time and energy they could spend on other issues.

Comment: @hfmaciver - I'm not sure I understand your argument. In your posting, you mention the fact that loading the `ltablex` package modifies *all* `tabularx` environments, and that this is something you don't want to see happen. Having tables span more than one page is not something that can be automated entirely; some judgment, common sense, and attention to detail are needed. If you load the `ltxtable` package, you can work specifically on the table that spans more than one page while leaving the other `tabularx` environments unaffected -- which, if I understand you correctly, is what you want.

Comment: Please also note, just in case you haven't done so already, that the `ltablex` package (which you mention in your posting) and the `ltxtable` package (which I mentioned in an earlier comment) are *not* the same. Have you given the `ltxtable` package and method a try?

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new here, and didn't see the lower comments.
I'm not sure I understand how the `ltxtable` works, is there and example about?

Comment: There are quite a few postings on this site that show to use the `ltxtable` package. See, for instance, [How to set the width of column in longtable method?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153771/5001) and [Textwidth longtable with centered headers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153422/5001).

Comment: Are there any news here?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do this using `ltxtable`:

1. Table goes in a separate file; environment `longtable`; with `tabularx`-style `X` column specifiers where needed.
2. Insert the table using `\LTXtable{<target-width>}{<file>}`, setting the desired width and choosing the appropriate file which contains the `longtable` environment.

One note: the `center` environment adds additional vertical space which might not be desired in some usage. It might be better to use `{\centering <content to be centered>}` in some situations (usually inside `figure`/`table` environments), which does not insert extra vertical space. I've shown the `\centering` method here, but it's up to you to decide based on how this is included in your document.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mytable.tex}
\begin{longtable}{|l X l|}
\hline
& \textbf{HEADING} & \textbf{HEADING} \bigstrut \tabularnewline
\hline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \bigstrut[t] \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\textbf{Number} & \textbf{WORDS} & \textbf{WORD} \bigstrut[t] \tabularnewline
& TEXT & \tabularnewline
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage{ltxtable}    % This is the package I would like to apply to a single table
\usepackage{bigstrut} 
\begin{document} 

{\centering
  \LTXtable{\textwidth}{mytable}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]