# Textwidth longtable with centered headers

Tags: longtable

I'm trying to create a `longtable` which spans the entire `\textwidth`. Additionally, although the contents of the table use different alignments, all of the header cells should be centered. Based upon e.g. [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54302/how-to-fit-landscape-multi-page-table-to-textwidth), I have come up with the following code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} | l | c | c | r | r | }
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Header 1}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Header 2}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Header 3}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Header 4}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Header 5}} \\
\hline
\endhead
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

When rendered with `pdflatex`, however, the first column is correctly centered, but the remaining columns seem to be right-aligned instead. I believe that the problem is that I'm misunderstanding how `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` works in the `longtable` definition.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mico's given a nice answer but just to comment that you should never use `\noindent` before longtable (or any display environment) it won't affect the indentation, just add a blank line of spurious space. `\extracolsep and vertical lines don't really work together in normal tabular either so it's not all my fault they don't really work in lingtable:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have two main choices, both of which have their aesthetic merits:

- Keep using your current `longtable` setup, but don't use vertical bars to separate the columns visually. Give it a try: I'm confident you won't miss those vertical rules at all.
- Load the `tabularx` and `ltxtable` packages as well, and use the `X` column type for the headers of the `longtable` environment. The only, but fortunately fairly minor, drawback of this method is that you need to place the entire longtable material in a separate file. This drawback can be mitigated by using the `filecontents` package to include the contents of the `longtable` in the document's preamble. The macro `\LTXtable{\textwidth}{<filename>}` is then used to load the external longtable.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,tabularx,ltxtable}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\LTleft{0pt}
\setlength\LTright{0pt}

% same as posted by OP
\begin{filecontents*}{mytable0.tex} 
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} | l | c | c | r | r | }
\caption{Longtable with extra ``fill'' and vertical rules}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Header 1}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Header 2}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Header 3}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Header 4}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Header 5}} \\
\hline
\endhead
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{mytable1.tex}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}  l  c  c  r  r  }
\caption{Longtable with extra ``fill'' and no vertical rules}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Header 1}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Header 2}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Header 3}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Header 4}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Header 5}} \\
\hline
\endhead
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{filecontents*}{mytable2.tex}
\begin{longtable}{ | l | c | c | r | r | }
\caption{Longtable, ``centered X'' column types}\\
\hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|Y|}{\textbf{Header 1}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{ Y|}{\textbf{Header 2}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{ Y|}{\textbf{Header 3}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{ Y|}{\textbf{Header 4}} &
    \multicolumn{1}{ Y|}{\textbf{Header 5}} \\
\hline
\endhead
\end{longtable}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\LTXtable{\textwidth}{mytable0.tex} % initial look

\LTXtable{\textwidth}{mytable1.tex}

\LTXtable{\textwidth}{mytable2.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 (seems  you've beat me to post on my packages several times today:-)

Comment: Both of these solutions work beautifully. Thanks!

Comment: @CmdrMoozy - Thanks for letting me know that both solutions work for you.